# Kuratowski closure axioms proof $cl(\bigcap E_{\alpha}) \subset \bigcap cl(E_{\alpha})$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{E_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then, $cl(\bigcap E_{\alpha}) \subset \bigcap cl(E_{\alpha})$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms

I am curious how to prove this with the Kuratowski closure operators. The proof is easy with just the intersection definition of closure i.e. $E_{\alpha} \subset \overline{E_{\alpha}}$ for all $\alpha \in I$. Then, $\bigcap E_{\alpha} \subset \bigcap \overline{E_{\alpha}}$. Since $\bigcap \overline{E_{\alpha}}$ is closed and it contains $\bigcap E_{\alpha}$, thus $\overline{\bigcap E_{\alpha}} \subset \bigcap \overline{E_{\alpha}}$.

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed $\beta$ we have $\bigcap_{\alpha}E_\alpha \subseteq E_\beta$, and therefore by monotonicity $cl(\bigcap_{\alpha}E_\alpha) \subseteq cl(E_\beta)$.  Since this holds for all $\beta$, $cl(\bigcap_{\alpha}E_\alpha) \subseteq \bigcap_{\beta}cl(E_\beta)$.